# How to pass an id to a URL in php api to get the data

Tags: php, api

I have an api endpoint done using php that gets me back the outstanding balance of particular student based on the studentId passed. I get the correct response by passing the studentId as parameter in the format
"http://localhost/api/**getOutstandingBill.php?studentId=GC2022A0021**",
However, I need to pass the studentId to the url in this format:
"http://localhost/api/**getOutstandingBill/GC2022A0021**", but I have no idea how to do this in php. It's my first time doing an api in php, so I would really appreciate your guidance.
Here is what I have tried:

```
<?php
require_once '../db_config/config.php';
require_once './class/bills.php';
require_once 'jwt_utils.php';

header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *");
header('Content-Type: application/json; charset=UTF-8');
header("Access-Control-Allow-Methods: GET");

$database = new Database();
$db = $database->getConnection();
$item = new OutstandingBill($db);

$item->studentid = isset($_GET['studentId']) ? $_GET['studentId'] : die();

$bearer_token = get_bearer_token();
$is_jwt_valid = is_jwt_valid($bearer_token);


if ($is_jwt_valid) {
    $query = "SELECT * FROM tblbills WHERE student_id = '$item->studentid'";
    $studentExist = dbQuery($query);

    if (dbNumRows($studentExist) > 0) {

        $sql = "SELECT * FROM tblbills WHERE student_id='$item->studentid'";
        $result = dbQuery($sql);

        while ($row = dbFetchAssoc($result)) {
            $outstandingBill = [
                'student_id' => $row['student_id'],
                'full_name' => $row['full_name'],
                // 'department' => $row['departmentid']
                'payment_type' => $row['payment_type'],
                'amount' => $row['amount'],
                'discount_percent' => $row['discount_percent'],
                'status' => $row['status'],
                'invoice_number' => $row['invoiceid'],
                'due_year_month' => $row['billdate'],
            ];
        }

        echo json_encode(array(
            'success' => true,
            'message' => "The outstanding payment for student $item->studentid",
            'data' => array($outstandingBill)
        ));
    }
    else {
        echo json_encode(array(
            'success' => false,
            'message' => "There is NO student with id number $item->studentid",
            'error_code' => 404
        ));
    }
}
else {
    echo json_encode(array(
        'success' => false,
        'message' => "Please provide a valid token",
        'error_code' => 401
    ));
}

?>
```

Comment: You need to look up URL Rewriting and the `.htaccess` file

Comment: _Improvement suggestion:_ I would recommend that you read up on the [front controller pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Front_controller) and then use a [router](https://packagist.org/?query=router) to handle the URL's. It's how most frameworks and CMS's do it. And since you only need one single rule (that redirects all requests to non-existing files to index.php), it's easier to move it between web servers (not all use htaccess).

Comment: @M.Eriksson
I have created a .htaccess file within my htdocs folder and added the following lines:
-------------------


RewriteEngine On


RewriteRule ^getOutstandingBill/([0-9-]+)$ getOutstandingBill.php?studentId=$1 [L]
------------------------------------


And when I  make this call

(http://localhost/api/getOutstandingBill/GC2022A0021) in postman I get an error 404 Not Found

Comment: The rule `([0-9-]+)` will only match numbers while you need to match `GC2022A0021` which also contains letters. Try changing it to `([a-zA-Z0-9-]+)` (catches all alpha numeric characters)

Comment: I made that change and the error is still the same did that but am stil

Comment: You also have `/asu.com/api/` in the posted URL though/.

Comment: @M.Eriksson, yeah my bad, I actually got it working by adding the rewrite rule in the .htaccess

Answer (score 1):

Upon looking for the URL rewrite and the .htaccess as suggested in the comments section, I created the .htaccess file within my api-project folder and added the following to the file:

```js
Options - Multiviews
Options + FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine on

// I added these two lines as the bearer token for authorisation couldn't be seen in the live api but locally it could be seen without these two lines: 
RewriteCond % {
  HTTP: Authorization
} ^ (.*)
RewriteRule.*-[e = HTTP_AUTHORIZATION: % 1]

// Here is my url rewrite rule
RewriteRule ^ ([a - zA - Z0 - 9 - /]+)$ getOutstandingBill.php?studentId=$1
```